# how to negative bigdecimal's value in android

Tags: android, bigdecimal

i have a Big Decimal like this for example.
i want to negative it's value. it has a string.

```
String a = "65";
BigDecimal example = new BigDecimal(a);
//i want to have (-65)
```

Comment: try `Math.multiplyExact(example.intValue(), -1)`

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BigDecimal.negate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#negate%28%29)

```
String a = "65";
BigDecimal example = new BigDecimal(a);
System.out.println( example.negate() ); // prints -65
```

Comment: @sinclair: I'm not sure sorena has seen or understood that yet.

Comment: @sinclair :DD im really sorry. the moment i was noob and actually i made another account with another email. all of a sudden i just logged in into this account and saw your comment. marked it. sorry for the delay :D